# VTK cutter output

Tags: line, vtk

I am seeking a solution of connecting all the lines that have the same slope and share a common point. For example, after I load a STL file and cut it using a plane, the cutter output includes the points defining the contour. Connecting them one by one forms a (or multiple) polyline. However, some lines can be merged when their slopes are the same and they share a common point. E.g., [[0,0,0],[0,0,1]] and [[0,0,1],[0,0,2]] can be represented by one single line [[0,0,0],[0,0,2]].

I wrote a function that can analyse all the lines and connect them if they can be merged. But when the number of lines are huge, this process is slow. I am thinking in the VTK pipeline, is there a way to do the line merging?

Cheers!

```
plane = vtk.vtkPlane()
plane.SetOrigin([0,0,5])
plane.SetNormal([0,0,1])
cutter = vtk.vtkCutter()
cutter.SetCutFunction(plane)
cutter.SetInput(triangleFilter.GetOutput())
cutter.Update()

cutStrips = vtk.vtkStripper()
cutStrips.SetInputConnection(cutter.GetOutputPort())
cutStrips.Update()

cleanDataFilter = vtk.vtkCleanPolyData()
cleanDataFilter.AddInput(cutStrips.GetOutput())
cleanDataFilter.Update()
cleanData = cleanDataFilter.GetOutput()

print cleanData.GetPoint(0)
print cleanData.GetPoint(1)
print cleanData.GetPoint(2)
print cleanData.GetPoint(3)
print cleanData.GetPoint(4)
```

The output is:

(0.0, 0.0, 5.0)
(5.0, 0.0, 5.0)
(10.0, 0.0, 5.0)
(10.0, 5.0, 5.0)
(10.0, 10.0, 5.0)

Connect the above points one by one will form a polyline representing the cut result. As we can see, the line [point0, point1] and [point1, point2] can be merged.

Below is the code for merging the lines:
Assume that the LINES are represented by list: [[(p0),(p1)],[(p1),(p2)],[(p2),(p3)],...]

```
appended = 0
CurrentLine = LINES[0]
CurrentConnectedLine = CurrentLine
tempLineCollection = LINES[1:len(LINES)]
while True:
    for HL in tempLineCollection:
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        if checkParallelAndConnect(CurrentConnectedLine, HL):
            appended = 1
            LINES.remove(HL)
            CurrentConnectedLine = ConnectLines(CurrentConnectedLine, HL)
    processedPool.append(CurrentConnectedLine) 
    if len(tempLineCollection) == 1:
        processedPool.append(tempLineCollection[0])
    LINES.remove(CurrentLine)
    if len(LINES) >= 2:
        CurrentLine = LINES[0]
        CurrentConnectedLine = CurrentLine
        tempLineCollection = LINES[1:len(LINES)]
        appended = 0
    else:
        break
```

Solution:

I figured out a way of further accelerating this process using some vtk data structure. I found out that a polyline line will be stored in a cell, which can be checked by using GetCellType(). Since the point order for a polyline is sorted already, We do not need to search globally which lines are colinear with the current one. For each point on the polyline, I just need to check the point[i-1], point[i], point[i+1]. And if they are colinear, the end of the line will be updated to the next point. This process continues until the end of the polyline is reached. The speed increases by a huge amount compared with the global search approach.

Comment: Post that code you mentioned please.

Comment: @Daniel Hi mate, I have added the code. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the main source of slowness (depends on how many positive hits on the colinearity you have), but removing items from a vector is costly (O(n)), since it requires reorganizing the rest of the vector, you should avoid it. But even without hits on colinearity, the `LINES.remove(CurrentLine)` call is surely slowing things down and there isn't really any need for it - just leave the vector untouched, write the final results to a new vector (`processedPool`) and get rid of the `LINES` vector in the end. You can modify your algorithm by making a bool array (vector), initialized at "false" for each item, then when you remove a line, you don't actually remove it, but only mark it as "true" and you skip all lines for which you have "true", i.e. something like this (I don't speak python so the syntax is not accurate):

```
wasRemoved = bool vector of the size of LINES initialized at false for each entry
for CurrentLineIndex = 0; CurrentLineIndex < sizeof(LINES); CurrentLineIndex++
    if (wasRemoved[CurrentLineIndex])
        continue // skip a segment that was already removed
    CurrentConnectedLine = LINES[CurrentLineIndex]
    for HLIndex = CurrentLineIndex + 1; HLIndex < sizeof(LINES); HLIndex++:
        if (wasRemoved[HLIndex])
           continue;
        HL = LINES[HLIndex]
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        if checkParallelAndConnect(CurrentConnectedLine, HL):
            wasRemoved[HLIndex] = true
            CurrentConnectedLine = ConnectLines(CurrentConnectedLine, HL)
    processedPool.append(CurrentConnectedLine) 
    wasRemoved[CurrentLineIndex] = true // this is technically not needed since you won't go back in the vector anyway

LINES = processedPool
```

BTW, the really correct data structure for `LINES` to use for that kind of algorithm would be a linked list, since then you would have O(1) complexity for removal and you wouldn't need the boolean array. But a quick googling showed that that's not how lists are implemented in Python, also don't know if it would not interfere with other parts of your program. Alternatively, using a set might make it faster (though I would expect times similar to my "bool array" solution), see [python 2.7 set and list remove time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092759/python-2-7-set-and-list-remove-time-complexity)

If this does not do the trick, I suggest you measure times of individual parts of the program to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you mate @tomj, I experimented on your method and it increases the process speed a lot. Together with your suggestions, I figured out a way to accelerate it using vtk data structure. I edited the post and put my solution in it. Thank you again for your answer.